# rsync unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(820)

Tags: cygwin, vagrant, rsync

Out of the blue, upon `vagrant up`, rsync started throwing the error below:

```
There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /c/Users/David/Sandbox/citypantry/frontend/
Guest path: /home/citypantry/project/frontend
Command: rsync --verbose --archive -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=C:/bin/cygwin64/tmp/ssh.588 -o ControlPersist=10m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=true -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/David/Sandbox/citypantry/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key' --exclude .vagrant/ --exclude app/cache/ --exclude app/logs/ --exclude node_modules /c/Users/David/Sandbox/citypantry/frontend/ vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/citypantry/project/frontend
Error: Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
select: Interrupted system call
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(820) [sender=3.1.1]
```

This is Windows 10 running a cygwin (x64) with rsync 3.1.1 on ConEmu (x64). Nothing that I know of has changed in the system and the sync has worked for weeks without any problems.

**What does this error mean and how can I fix it?**

Comment: I think this is more question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with Vagrant 1.8.0: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6702

Updating it should solve the problem. If you can't then the workaround is to edit `$VAGRANT_HOME\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.0\plugins\synced_folders\rsync\helper.rb` and remove lines 77~79:

```
"-o ControlMaster=auto " +
"-o ControlPath=#{controlpath} " +
"-o ControlPersist=10m " +
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Broken pipe* error usually happens when you hit the connection timeout. It can happen with rsync when it's calculating the file differences on the remote and it didn't respond to the client on time.

To avoid this, try increasing the server alive interval value in your SSH config (`~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 6
```

Also consider doing similar on the remote (in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), e.g.

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 6
```

See: [What the options `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3026/21471)

---

Alternatively add the following keep alive line into your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.ssh.keep_alive = true
```

---

If you think it's a control master issue, the recent Vagrant version [ignore to use it on windows platforms](https://github.com/fluetm/vagrant/commit/6b92b9295d207d0f914e0ce4e99f08dfb69fbedf).